# Find a Minimum by Optimizing multiple constrained variables with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have data values `y`, which can be calculated by a function `y=A x B x exp(C)` where `A` and `C` are variables and `B` is a constant. The data values `y` are given for different `B`. I want to determine the variables `A` and `C`.

My idea was to define a ratio between the given data `y` and the calculated data `y` (`y_calc`). `y_calc` will be calculated with values of `A` and `C` which are near the real variables `A` and `C`. So this ratio needs to be minimized for all `y_calc` at different `B`.
--> `ratio = ((y - y_calc)/(y + y_calc))^2`.

Additionally, there are constraints for `A` and `C` (e.g. `A<10`, `C>20`). I also want to define constraints for the ratio (e.g. `ratio<1e-5`)

I want to solve this with MATLAB. Unfortunately, I have no idea which of the many available functions i have to use and how these functions will be applied.

Can anyone help me? Is it even possible to solve my problem this way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you made a typo in your OP like the other user suggested.

Your idea for getting started goes in the right direction, look up 'cost function'.

There's an fminsearch function you can use. I'm not that knowledgeable in this area because I learned all of this pretty recently, most of the time the SVD method (again look it up) is used for stuff like this.

This should work

```
clear all 
close all
clc

B = [1,2,3,4,5];     % test values B
y = [3,5,7,9,15];    % test values y
vParam = [1,1];      % starting test value A and C

fct='fct';
options=optimset('TolX', 1.e-4, 'TolFun', 1.e-4, 'MaxFunEvals', 1500,'MaxIter', 500);

[vParam_optimized] = fminsearch(fct,vParam,options,B,y);

fit = vParam_optimized(1).*B.*exp(vParam_optimized(2));

plot(fit)
hold on
plot(y,'*')

function y=fct(vParam,B,y_meas)
% Parameters, x values, y result values

    y=0;

    for i=1:length(B)
        y=y+(y_meas(i)-(vParam(1)*B(i)*exp(vParam(2)))).^2; % cost function
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked grat!
But how can I set constraints for the variables A and C? I couldn't find out.

Comment: Not sure myself to be honest, will try and look into it.